# what do these instructions do

Tags: assembly, msp430

I am working on a simulator for the msp430 instruction set.  gnu assembler will let you encode instructions like these:

```
fc0a: 12 10 00 02 rrc &0x0200       
fc0e: 22 11       rra #4        
fc10: 23 52       add #4,#2
```

My guess is that rrc &0x0200 will fetch from address 0x0200 perform the rotate then write the answer back to address 0x0200, correct?  But what would an rra #4 do?  The source would be an immediate 4 I assume but is there a destination after the operation?  The add #4,#2 assembled into what you would expect (as 2b10, source = r2, ad = 1b0, dest = r3), the binutils disassembler though did not know what to do with that instruction.

Are these valid instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there doesn't appears to be any definitive online reference to this effect, I tend to agree with the OP that the two instructions shown (and several others) **are likely not valid**, even though they conform to the format defined in the data sheets.

In other words, not all possible combinations of the various parts that make up a instruction word are valid.  In particular many single operand instructions that use the immediate addressing mode, and many double operand instructions that have an immediate addressing mode for the destination are probably not semantically viable.

There are only a few hints to this effect in the documentation, for example, in the User's Guide, section 3.3.7 (on the immediate addressing mode), a comment indicates "*Valid only for a source operand.*"  (And, BTW, this is for all cases of immediate addressing mode, not just the short-hand cases allowed by the R2 or R3 constant generation trick.)

The fact that the disassembler doesn't know what to do with such codes is also another hint (although... some disassemblers get tripped easily...).

For sake of documentation, I gathered below a few useful references for the MSP430:

- [TI's MSP430 User's Guide (pdf)](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf)  Chapter 3 is particularly relevant
- [The TI MSP430 microcontroller (pdf)](http://eleceng.dit.ie/frank/msp430/msp430.pdf)   A shorter overview (11 pages)
- [MSPGCC manual](http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x223.html)  A GNU Port of TI's tools for the MSP430 microcontrollers.

Comment: The 2nd bullet item appears to be a broken link.  Do you mean eleceng.dit.ie/frank/msp430/msp430.pdf?

Comment: Dan: I updated the link; thanks for identifying this issue.
Ramhound: yep 2 years old ;-)  Good thing to try and keep it up to date, however.

Answer (score 2):

In the current users guide, in section 3.4.4.2, it recommends not using the immediate mode (#N) in the destination field for the command RRA as it results in "unpredictable program operation."

Answer (score 1):

It's possible they are. Looking at the instruction set on Wikipedia, the opcodes encode the register and various options. So it's not a simple mapping. It looks like the output you've got is little-endian, so this:

```
fc0a: 12 10 00 02 rrc &0x0200
```

corresponds to the instruction 1012, which in binary is 0001 0000 0001 0010.

This breaks down as follows:

```
6 bits: 0001 00 - fixed; defines the instruction family
3 bits: 00 0    - instruction (RRC)
1 bit : 0       - byte or word parameter (0 = 16 bit parameter; 1 = 8 bit)
2 bits: 01      - addressing mode (01 = indexed;)
4 bits: 0010    - register
```

So in this case a rotate-right is occuring on the value at the offset in register 2 from address &0200.

You'd need to break the other instructions down in a similar way to fully understand. For the ADD instruction, both the source and destination registers/addresses are encoded in the 
5223 instruction.

Comment: That is what I am talking about, the question is, for example, can you rotate right with a single operand that is a constant.  Where does the result go?  Or when you add one constant with another where does the result go?  Does the computation happen and flags change but no output or is it an illegal instruction from the start?

Comment: When I've used other instruction sets, the rotate happens on the target, so yes you can rotate right with a single operand. The operand is an indictator to where the data you want to rotate lives, and the value is written back into that location.

There's a better version of the instruction set here http://cnx.org/content/m23503/latest/   .... this includes the actual physical operation that occurs to the given location.