# MSP430 assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, processor, msp430

I am trying to understand what these instructions do for the MSP 430 processor:

```
(1) MOV.w  #0x0055,R5
(2)   BIC.w  #0xFFEE,R5
(3)   BIS.w  #0x1144,R5
```

I haven't been able to find much that explains the assembly instructions and would love to find out what these instructions do and what is stored in the r5 register after each instruction. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MOV` moves a value to the destination. In this case `R5` will contain the value 0x0055.

`BIC` clears bits in the destination value. If R5 would contain 0x0055 before the instruction, it will contain the value 0x0011. (Think of this as an inversed *and* instruction).

`BIS` sets bits -- this is effectively the same as an *or* operation. `R5` will have the value 0x1155 after this instruction.

Answer (score 5):

`MOV.w  #0x0055,R5` does the following:  `src → dst`

`BIC.w  #0xFFEE,R5` does the following `not.src .and. dst → dst`

`BIS.w  #0x1144,R5` does the following: `src .or. dst → dst`

Just look at the [MSP 430 User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf)

> BIS[.W]                         Set bits in destination BIS.B
>   Set bits in destination
>
> Syntax                          BIS               src,dst      or
>   BIS.W         src,dst BIS.B            src,dst
>
> Operation                     src .OR. dst −> dst
>
> Description                  The source operand and the destination
>   operand are logically ORed. The  result is placed into the
>   destination. The source operand is not affected.
>
> Status Bits                   Status bits are not affected.
>
> Mode Bits                     OSCOFF, CPUOFF, and GIE are not
>   affected.
>
> Example                       The six LSBs of the RAM word TOM are
>   set.
>
> BIS               #003Fh,TOM; set the six LSBs in RAM location TOM
>
> Example                       The three MSBs of RAM byte TOM are set.
>
> BIS.B            #0E0h,TOM          ; set the 3 MSBs in RAM location
>   TOM

Of Course:

> BIC[.W]                         Clear bits in destination BIC.B
>   Clear bits in destination
>
> Syntax                          BIC               src,dst      or
>   BIC.W  src,dst BIC.B            src,dst
>
> Operation                     .NOT.src .AND. dst −> dst
>
> Description                  The  inverted  source  operand  and  the 
>   destination  operand are  logically ANDed. The result is placed into
>   the destination. The source operand is not affected.
>
> Status Bits                   Status bits are not affected.
>
> Mode Bits                     OSCOFF, CPUOFF, and GIE are not
>   affected.
>
> Example                       The six MSBs of the RAM word LEO are
>   cleared.
>
> BIC               #0FC00h,LEO                    ; Clear 6 MSBs in
>   MEM(LEO)
>
> Example                       The five MSBs of the RAM byte LEO are
>   cleared.
>
> BIC.B            #0F8h,LEO                        ; Clear 5 MSBs in
>   Ram location LEO

I was able to find this user guide with a related link on this [very website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429116/what-do-these-instructions-do?rq=1)

Comment: What possible reason could anyone have to down vote this question?

Comment: Perhaps they object to spoon-feeding people who ask bad questions, or think that copying that much documentation into an answer is overkill.  I think some people just downvote the question and most of the answers on questions they think shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of information missing from the existing answers is the significance of .W vs .B.

From Section 3.4 of the MSP430F24x User Guide (SLAU144J) on page 56 it specifies,

> B/W:
>
> Byte or word operation:
>
> 0: word operation
>
> 1: byte operation

It is worth noting that the default is that instructions operate on a word.

Comment: This is not the same instruction set or syntax, however this link describes suffixes which are sort of common across many assembly languages (not all). https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes